# No puedo Deployar mi proyecto en Render(he probado railway,vercel,fly.io y Tampoco!)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, hosting, deployment

es un ecommerce que vengo desarrollando hace meses y ahora me encuentro con este problema al deployear. Las Tecnologías que estoy utilizando para el front son Javascript Html y css, y para el back JS node express y de BD google sheets.

El proyecto levanta correctamente de manera local:
Si quisieras hacerlo simplemente clonas el proyecto de github, luego un npm install para instalar el node modules y el resto de dependencias,
y para levantar con un npm run start ya lo tienes en el puerto 3000.

el primer problema con el que me encuentro es que la mayoría de hostings pide un build command[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y yo no utilizo ningun npm build start o algo parecido. Razon por la cual señale en este apartado el npm install. pero al momento de deployear lo unico que se ve en pantalla es "Cannot GET /"
y el error de consola:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().
Les comparto tambien una imagen de mi Package.json y como es masomenos la estructura de mi proyecto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
package.json

```
{
  "name": "vionza-ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Lukezet",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/local-auth": "^2.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "googleapis": "^105.0.0",
    "mercadopago": "^1.5.17"
  }
}
```

este es el Index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
//cargar var de entorno
require('dotenv').config();
//npm install body-parser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const repositoryBD = require("./repositoryBD");
const mercadopago = require('mercadopago');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Agrega credenciales
mercadopago.configure({
    access_token: "TEST-6776565151351351352720-af722b98cb08264a72a9-4477",
  });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await repositoryBD.read());
});

app.post('/api/pay', async (req, res) => {
    const order = req.body;
    const productsCopy = await repositoryBD.read();
    const unavailableProducts = [];

    let preference = {
        items: [],
        back_urls: {
            "success": "http://localhost:3000/feedback",
            "failure": "http://localhost:3000/feedback",
            "pending": "http://localhost:3000/feedback"
        },
        auto_return: "approved",
      };

    order.cartProducts.forEach(item => {
        const product = productsCopy.find(p => p.id == item.product.id);// Buscar el producto por ID
        let cantReal = 0
        if (product) {
            cantReal = product.talles[item.talle];
            
            if (cantReal !== undefined && cantReal > 0) {
                
                console.log("cantidad real:"+cantReal+ "cantidad enviada"+ item.cant);
                if(cantReal<item.cant){//verificamos si es factible comprar la cantidad que agregamos y si hay menos enviamos lo que queda de stock en ese talle
                    product.talles[item.talle]-=cantReal;
                    preference.items.push({
                        title: product.name,
                        unit_price: product.price,
                        quantity: parseInt(cantReal),
                    });
                }else{
                    product.talles[item.talle]-=item.cant;
                    preference.items.push({
                        title: product.name,
                        unit_price: product.price,
                        quantity: parseInt(item.cant),
                    });
                }
                
             }else{
                unavailableProducts.push(product.name); // Agregar productos no disponibles a la lista
                console.log("producto no disponible");
            }
        }
    });
    // products = productsCopy;
    // res.send(products);

    if (unavailableProducts.length === 0) {
        const response = await mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
        const preferenceId = response.body.id;

        await repositoryBD.write(productsCopy);//descontamos del stock
        order.date = new Date().toISOString();
        order.preferenceId = preferenceId;
        order.status = "pending";
        const orders = await repositoryBD.readOrders();//traemos y leemos todas las ordenes que hay en sheet
        order.idOrder = orders[orders.length-1].idOrder + 1;//agregamos el numero de orden(idOrder)
        orders.push(order);//agregamos los datos a la nueva orden
        await repositoryBD.writeOrders(orders);//generamos la orden de compra

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, preferenceId });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Algunos productos no están disponibles', unavailableProducts });
    }
});



app.post('/api/payByTransfer', async (req, res) => {
    const order = req.body;
    const productsCopy = await repositoryBD.read();
    const unavailableProducts = [];

    order.cartProducts.forEach(item => {
        const product = productsCopy.find(p => p.id == item.product.id);// Buscar el producto por ID
        let cantReal = 0
        if (product) {
            cantReal = product.talles[item.talle];

            if (cantReal !== undefined && cantReal > 0) {
                console.log("disponible");
             }else{
                unavailableProducts.push(product.name); // Agregar productos no disponibles a la lista
                console.log("producto no disponible");
            }
        }
    });
    // products = productsCopy;
    // res.send(products);

    if (unavailableProducts.length === 0) {

        await repositoryBD.write(productsCopy);//descontamos del stock
        order.date = new Date().toISOString();
        order.preferenceId = "TRANSFERENCIA";
        order.status = "pending";
        const orders = await repositoryBD.readOrders();//traemos y leemos todas las ordenes que hay en sheet
        order.idOrder = orders[orders.length-1].idOrder + 1;//agregamos el numero de orden(idOrder)
        let orderNumber = order.idOrder; 
        orders.push(order);//agregamos los datos a la nueva orden
        await repositoryBD.writeOrders(orders);//generamos la orden de compra

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, orderNumber });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Algunos productos no están disponibles', unavailableProducts });
    }
});



app.get('/feedback', async (req, res) => {
    const payment = await mercadopago.payment.findById(req.query.payment_id);
    const merchantOrder = await mercadopago.merchant_orders.findById(payment.body.order.id);
    const preferenceId = merchantOrder.body.preference_id;
    const status = payment.body.status;
    await repositoryBD.updateOrderByPreferenceId(preferenceId,status);

    res.sendFile(require.resolve("./frontend/index.html"))
});

app.use("/",express.static("frontend"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Desde ya muchas gracias a aquellos dispuestos a ayudar le he metido muchas horas a este proyecto y sería una verdadera pena dejarlo así..

Comment: Agrega el código como texto.

Comment: En lugar de mandar una URL que puede que algún día no esté disponible, la forma correcta es que añadas el código aquí, en tu pregunta y no esperes que alguien lo haga por ti, que aunque puede que lo hagan, no es buena idea esperar que otros hagan tu trabajo.

Comment: @LucasYañezBogni son reglas del sitio, de hecho cuando agregas imágenes te dice que por favor no agregues el código como imagen.

Comment: ok lo siento no lo sabía, y pense que sería mas comodo interpretarlo desde github Ahora lo añado, gracias!

Comment: Ojo con colocar credenciales, aunque sean de testeo.